# Why does emacs does not find psql?

Tags: postgresql, emacs

This is somewhat weird, I compiled from source `postgresql`. I've had no problem using psql at all.

```
$ psql -d rita
psql (9.3.2)
Type "help" for help.

rita=>
```

`

However when I try to run `M-x sql-postgres` on emacs, it prompts for user, password, database, host. But when I input the data in the minibuffer just appears: `Unable to locate SQL program psql`. I hope anyone can tell me how can I fix this, or what is happening.

Comment: What does `which psql` show?

Comment: `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql` is what I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `psql` isn't on the standard path.

You are likely setting the `PATH` in
`~/.bashrc`, and Emacs will not see it unless you launch Emacs from the terminal.

A solution is:

```lisp
(setq sql-postgres-program "/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql")
```

Or `ln -s` to `/usr/bin` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add the path to the psql binary to your emacs 'exec-path list as follows:

```
 (add-to-list 'exec-path "/path/to/program")
 (setenv PATH (mapconcat 'identity exec-path ":"))
```

I run Emacs on a Mac as my development environment. Launching emacs from the Dock doesn't include the path for programs installed via MacPorts. This is going to be a standard problem for anyone who has "non-standard" exec path elements and launches Emacs via their GUI. For me, OSX : MacPorts : /opt/local/... this includes psql, mysql, py-flakes and others. I could either set a variable for each add-on or modify exec-path. The setenv is needed where the elisp function defers searching the exec-path to the shell. The C-c C-v binding in python mode leverages the shell and the $PATH environment to find py-flakes.

The *add-to-list* is a simple solution that prepends the path to the list. One could make a case for more complex path wrangling in your .emacs file. YMMV.